# RxJS: JSON move an object property a level below

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following JSON:

[image]

my `apps` is an array of objects. the `apps` array is inside another json object that wraps it. I created the following method to return the list of apps:

```
return this.http.get(`analytics`)
      .map((data: any) => { return data.apps; } );
```

Now, as you can see in the screenshot, there is a `bandwidth` object with a `total` property. I need to move the `total` property inside the `bandwidth` inner object to be in the first level of the app list:

[image]

How I can achieve that using RxJS?

Comment: Have you tried any approach?

Comment: RxJS allows to process a stream. Since data is a regular object, you process it like regular object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 return this.http.get(`analytics`)
      .map((data: any) => { 
            return data.apps.map((app)=>{
                if(app.bandwidth && app.bandwidth.total){
                    app.total = app.bandwidth.total;
                    delete app.bandwidth.total;
                }
                return app;
            }); 
       } );
```